# Spring WebFlux. How to add specific logic after controller call?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I have the next `RestController`:

```java
@PostMapping("/play")
public Mono<PlayResponse> play(@RequestBody String body) {
    //business logic here;
}
```

And I wanna add some additional logic after the controller call. For example, I want to add to my application some `modes` logic:

- `timeout mode` - after the successful call, the response will wait until timeout happens
- `long answer mode` - after the successful call, the response will wait a particular amount of ms
- `failure mode` - after the successful call, the response will answer with `FORBIDDEN` code
- etc.

I'm trying to achieve that through `WebFilter`:

```java
@Component
public class OutgoingFilter implements WebFilter {

    Mode mode = new TimeoutMode();

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(@NonNull final ServerWebExchange exchange, final WebFilterChain chain) {
        return chain.filter(exchange)
                .doOnNext(this::onNext)
                .map(this::onMap)
                .doFinally(this::onFinally);
    }

    private Void onMap(final Void unused) {
        mode.run();
        return unused;
    }

    private void onNext(final Void unused) {
        mode.run();
    }

    private void onFinally(final SignalType signalType) {
        mode.run();
    }

}
```

As you can see, I've tried `onMap`, `doOnNext` and`onFinally` methods and none of them seem not working.

Is it the right way to use `WebFilter` there? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?
How can I implement such logic in the `Spring WebFlux` application?

---

**Update**

There is my `Mode` interface:

```java
public interface Mode {
    void run() throws Forbidden;
}
```

Implementations:

```java
public class Fail implements Mode {
    @Override
    public void run() throws Forbidden {
        throw new Forbidden("Fail mode enabled");
    }
}
```

```java
public class Wait implements Mode {

    private final int ms;

    public Wait() {
        this(0);
    }

    public Wait(final int ms) {
        this.ms = ms;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() throws Forbidden {
        sleep();
    }

    private void sleep() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

But the implementations aren't final. I will change them to a `reactive` style if it's needed.

Comment: What is that `Mode` interface, and what is the `run` method? Is that reactive as well? If so without a subscription to it it won't do anything.

Comment: @M.Deinum I've added some examples